# Ran into a problem installing plugins with Composer

Tags: plugins, composer

I'm using Composer to install plugins with the wpackagist repository. I've added all the relevant lines to my `composer.json` file in my main `wp/` directory.

The plugin installed as expected (it's [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) if it makes any difference) to its own folder within `wp/plugins/`.

The issue that I see now is that it doesn't show up in the plugins section of my WordPress dashboard, nor am I able to install it with `wp plugin activate <name>`.

Is there something else that needs to be done with Composer or elsewhere in this process to allow the plugin to be able to be installed?

Here's my `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "johnpbloch/wordpress-core",
  "description": "WordPress is web software you can use to create a beautiful website or blog.",
  "repositories":[
    {
        "type":"composer",
        "url":"https://wpackagist.org"
    }
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "wordpress",
    "blog",
    "cms"
  ],
  "type": "wordpress-core",
  "homepage": "http://wordpress.org/",
  "license": "GPL-2.0+",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "WordPress Community",
      "homepage": "http://wordpress.org/about/"
    }
  ],
  "support": {
    "issues": "http://core.trac.wordpress.org/",
    "forum": "http://wordpress.org/support/",
    "wiki": "http://codex.wordpress.org/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/wordpress",
    "source": "http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser"
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "wpackagist-plugin/members": "2.0.2"
  },
  "provide": {
    "wordpress/core-implementation": "4.8.2"
  }
}
```

As I mentioned, the plugin is visible in my `wp-plugins` folder, so it seems to have done everything correctly. I just can't manage to install it neither with WP-CLI nor within the WP Dashboard.

Comment: Is the `wp`-folder equivalent to the `wp-content`-folder in which the plugins-folder usually resides? can you share your composer.json for more insight?

Comment: @websupporter `wp` folder is the top-level folder containing all of the WordPress core files as well as folders like `wp-content`.

Answer (score 2):

In order for WordPress to recognize a plugin it needs to be in the correct plugins folder.

In an usual installation this is wp-content/plugins/

If you use wpackagist.org, a working example would be this composer.json:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "wpackagist-plugin/broken-link-checker": "*",
    "wpackagist-theme/twentyseventeen": "*"
  }
}
```

`wpackagist-plugin` signals its a WordPress plugin you want to install `wpackagist-theme` signals, its a theme.

I hope, this helps.

If you want to manage your whole installation (including WordPress), I suggest you have a look into [WPStarter](https://github.com/wecodemore/wpstarter)

**Edit:**

I tested your composer.json like this:

In the folder, where I have my composer.json I run

`wp core download
wp config create ...
wp core install ...
composer install`

and it was working for me. My guess was maybe file rights. Could it be, the directory is not readable for the PHP instance?

Comment: I've just added my `composer.json` file. It seems to have all installed correctly and the plugin folder is right where expected at `wp-content/plugins/`. I just can't activate it neither with WP-CLI or in the dashboard.

Comment: @Akor updated my answer. suspecting right now file rights. The composer.json worked in my tests.

Comment: Figured out the issue. I'm using a boilerplate called Bedrock and it seems I was using the wrong `composer.json`. I used the root-level one and everything worked fine! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, this is not *your* `composer.json`, this is the `composer.json` of [`johnpbloch/wordpress-core`](https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-core/blob/master/composer.json) – which is not supposed to be used as a base for your own project, but as a dependency instead.

Better have a look at [`roots/bedrock`](https://github.com/roots/bedrock) and start your project with it. Or more minimalistic with [`wodby/wordpress-composer`](https://github.com/wodby/wordpress-composer). You could also try it with the sample `composer.json` on the https://wpackagist.org/ front-page, but then you also have to build some more logic around it on your own – as of where exactly you want these packages to be installed to, in which directory.

`wp/plugins/` isn't actually the default folder where plugins should be installed to. So you either need to make WordPress recognize this folder as plugin directory or you should install them into their default directory `wp-content/plugins/`.

---

However, what's really missing in your question is: What plugin *exactly*? What command did you run *exactly*? And what was the output when you run `wp plugin activate NAME`? What does "I just can't manage to install" mean?